# Counter Clockwise stroke on CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, core-animation, cashapelayer

How do you set the direction for the strokeStart and strokeEnd on a CAShapeLayer

This is what you get out of the box. (strokeEnd is 0.75)

[image]

How can you make it move the opposite way (strokeEnd is 0.75)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `strokeEnd`, but the `CGPath` that you're using and that is clockwise.

I guess you want this: `[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:yourRect] bezierPathByReversingPath].CGPath`

EDIT:

another way would have been to use

```
strokeStart = 1 - strokeEnd; // not sure about the name "strokeStart"
strokeEnd = 1;
```

but the reversed path represents your intentions better